# C Windows API: Polygon accept mouse input

Tags: c, windows, api, polygon

Say I create a polygon with the `Polygon` function, and i'd like it to accept input from the mouse (similar to a button).

How would I do that?

***EDIT:***
Processing the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages, I'm using this code to check if the mouse is in the area of the polygon:

```
if (LOWORD(lParam) < 375 && LOWORD(lParam) > 340 &&
    HIWORD(lParam) < 200 && HIWORD(lParam) > 90)
```

Problem is, the polygon is not a rectangle, its a polygon. So how would I go about detecting if the mouse was in the polygon only?

***EDIT 2:*** I should also note, its only a triangle lol. Hope that makes this simpler.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, it only has 3 points.

Comment: That's often known as a triangle! ;-) Pretty easy to work out a hit test for that. I bet one of the sides is horizontal or vertical.

Comment: fully general polygon testing covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test

Comment: This is covered pretty well in Windows with the GraphicsPath::IsVisible() function.  That's however a C++ method, getting fancy in C is not that well supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Polygon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162814%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a function that is used to draw to a device context. As such it cannot receive inupt. You need a windowed control to do that.

Handle the input in your window and use a hit test to check if you are inside the polygon.

Comment: One way to do this is to create a path from the polygon, convert the path to a region, and then use PtInRegion.

Comment: @raymond indeed, but perhaps overkill for a triangle!!

Answer (score 0):

A polygon can't accept input, it must be done through the window that the polygon was drawn on. Listen for the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message and look at the coordinates delivered with the message; determine if the coordinate is within the polygon or not. The easiest way to do that might be to draw the polygon on a bitmap the same size as the window, and test the point on the bitmap to see if it is the polygon color or not.